# Security Exception when calling user.getPhotoUrl() Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working on a android app where i have to allow a user to register with a profile picture, i'm able to register the user with fields like username,email and the photo. The problem arises when i try to log back in with the same user i just created which gave me the error below....

Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.docs.storagebackend.StorageBackendContentProvider from ProcessRecord .................requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs

Below is my code for creating the user

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                .setDisplayName(uname).setPhotoUri(ImgUri).build();

                        user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, Login.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration failed! Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Here's my code for picking the image

```
private void chooseImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        ImgUri = data.getData();
        System.out.println(ImgUri);

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), ImgUri);
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.userImg);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And Below is my code when i'm trying to retrieve the user profile Picture

```
  FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    System.out.println(user.getPhotoUrl());
    img.setImageURI(user.getPhotoUrl());
```

Am i required to save the ImageUri to Firebase Storage as well as Firebase Realtime Database? Or are there any permissions required ? Am i required

Comment: just use `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);` instead of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`

Comment: @diginoise Thanks for the help, i was stuck on this for hours

Answer (score 1):

Add Action to intent while picking up the image

```
private void chooseImage() {
   Intent intent=Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
   intent.setType("image/*");
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 
   PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

> ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is not intended to be a replacement for  ACTION_GET_CONTENT. The one you should use depends on the needs of your app:
>
> Use ACTION_GET_CONTENT if you want your app to simply read/import data. With this approach, the app imports a copy of the data, such as an image file.
>
> Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT if you want your app to have long term, persistent access to documents owned by a document provider. An example would be a photo-editing app that lets users edit images stored in a document provider.

Answer (score 0):

set firebase storage rule to access storage.

open firebase deshboard >> go on storage >> in storage move on Rules tab.
change your own rule for access your storage, i'm sharing rule with all access.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/shoppingappwithfcm.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```